# iOS8 - Prevent scrolling when text area is focused

Tags: javascript, cordova, ios8

i'm trying to prevent my page from scrolling when the user is focusing an input (in my case, the textarea).

The solution i was using worked so far under iOS7 (`window.scrollTo(0, 0)`), but since iOS8, this solution isn't working correctly since the page is scrolling on focus before scrolling back to the original position.

The other solution aren't working either, so i'd like to find some tricks to prevent my page from scrolling.

Comment: "prevent from scrolling" but when exactly? Are you talking about the keyboard coming up and pushing the page up a lil bit or some other scrolling?

Comment: Yup, but it's not a little bit, it's like 100 pixels while there's enough room for the keyboard to be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the IONIC plugin keyboard should be the solution

> **Keyboard.disableScroll**
>
> Disable native scrolling, useful if you are using JavaScript to scroll
>
> cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
>
> cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard

Comment: I'll have a look at it on monday.